# Heroku router status 400 cause="bad header" code=H26 on requests with connection header set to upgrade

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js

I'm dealing with a weird issue where https requests made to my express.js API hosted on heroku are returning status code 400 when the connection header is set to 'upgrade'.

This is what the log looks like in heroku

`2022-04-04T03:44:57.958428+00:00 heroku[router]: cause="bad header" at=error code=H26 desc="Request Error" method=GET path="/v1/get?id=10" host=ulleo-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a38920e7-4ab5-4f7f-825c-0c90199af490 fwd="127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" dyno= connect= service= status=400 bytes= protocol=https`

I don't think it's possible for me to change the header because it's being set by the browser during a nuxt SSR http request, the request works fine in the browser as the connection header is set to keep-alive, but for some reason when doing SSR nuxt sets it to upgrade which is breaking the heroku router.

Any idea what could fix this?

I'm making the request with Axios, when I try setting the connection header to 'keep-alive' it throws an error saying it's an unsafe header, ie. the client controls the header.

Kindly

I've tried manually overwriting the connection header with the keep-alive value but I get an error about setting unsafe headers, upon researching this is because this header is controlled by the client

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Heroku Support they asked what the value of the `Upgrade` header was, I had a look and it wasn't being set, after trying to set it to HTTP/1.1 the request still failed, but after setting it to a random value such as `'none'` or `'xyz'` the request seemed to work fine.

I guess setting an invalid `Upgrade` header value makes Heroku ignore the connection upgrade request.